# Зачем в данном случае удалять класс?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Непонятен фрагмент кода в строке 1. Надо реализовать подсветку ячейки  при клике.

Вместо того, чтобы назначать обработчик для каждой ячейки, которых может быть очень много – мы повесим единый обработчик на элемент .

Он будет использовать event.target, чтобы получить элемент, на котором произошло событие, и подсветить его. Т.е  я если не пойму почему если selectedTd) удалить класс  highlight из свойства classList?

```js
table.onclick = function(event) {
 let target = event.target.closest('td')
  if (target)
   highlight(target)
}

var selectedTd;
function highlight(node) {
  if (selectedTd) {
    selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight'); // 1*
  }
  selectedTd = node;
  selectedTd.classList.add('highlight');
}
```

Comment: Чтобы удалить подсветку с предыдущего элемента, чтобы подсветок не было больше одной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.onclick = function(event) {
  let target = event.target.closest('td');
  if (target){
    highlight(target); // Не хочется неприятных сюрпризов - хорошо бы всегда ставить ; и {}
  }
}

var selectedTd; // undefined
function highlight(node) {
  if (selectedTd) {// пока undefined = вернет false и не выполнится.
    selectedTd.classList.remove('highlight'); // 1*
  }
  selectedTd = node;
  // Определили его = кликнутый (еще не подкрашенный) элемент; Он же let target = ...

  selectedTd.classList.add('highlight'); // Покрасили;
}
```

На следующем клике selectedTd уже будет определен == предыдущий кликнутый и покрашенный элемент. Условие вернет true, краска уберется, потом уже переменная переопределится в новый кликнутый элемент и так по кругу.